# I don't find the CSS styled-components is supposed to inject to DOM

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, styled-components

I am trying to get under the hoods of styled-components library.
reading this article have helped me a-lot: 
[How styled-components works](https://medium.com/styled-components/how-styled-components-works-618a69970421)

But there is something I can't fully understand:
the article describes how styled-component creates the 'style' tag inside the 'head' section and 
at runtime **injects the component style in-there.**
[image]
so I have created a minimal react project and the UI is working fine, except I **don't

see the injected CSS style in the DOM.** 
I do see an empty styled tag in the head:`<style data-styled-components=""></style>`. 
scratching my head how the css manages to apply successfully...
I even downgraded the library version to 3.3.3, the same as in the article - and it still doesn't work.
Assuming it will be more efficient to ask Stack-overflow than in the article,
may be someone here can help?

- webpack-config:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // base path where to send compiled assets
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        // config for sass compilation
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      // plugin for inserting scripts automatically into html
      template: 'src/index.html',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // plugin for controlling how compiled css will be outputted and named
      filename: '[name].css',
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

- the react code

```js
import React from 'react'
import styled  from 'styled-components'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


let counter = 6

const Button = styled.button`
  color: coral; 
  padding: 0.25rem 1rem; 
  border: solid 2px coral; 
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  font-size: ${({size}) => {  return size }}px; 
`

const MyButton = (props) => {
    return (<Button onClick={()=>update()} size={props.size}> Hi, I am your new button </Button>)
}

const update=()=>{
    counter ++;
    ReactDOM.render(<MyButton size={counter}/>, document.getElementById('root'))
}

export default MyButton
```

:

Comment: When you say you don't "see" it, do you mean when looking at the page using dev tools? Or is it not applying the style at all?

Comment: @DBS  The style is applied successfully - the button looks great, 
but I just dont see the CSS in the DOM via dev-tools, as it described in the article

Comment: I don't see where he says that but one cannot inject CSS into the DOM. That's impossible. The DOM does not hold CSS styling.

Comment: @Rob look for the text in the article:
"If you check generated styles in dev tools after a few clicks you will see:"
I also added a screen-shot of the article above